# Not asking permission for fetching contacts from user's address book

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

I have to access user contacts from his phone book and show it in skstableview. 
For getting contact and showing it on tableview I am using below code but neither it is not asking for accessing contact permission nor getting contacts and print this statement on console:

> "Access Denied" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Access Denied, NSLocalizedFailureReason=This application has not been granted permission to access Contacts.}

I have done entry in plist file for accessing contacts but nothing is working for me.

Here is the code snippet which I am using in Xcode 8.3.3 in swift.

```
 func getContacts() {
    let store = CNContactStore()

    if CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts) == .notDetermined {

        store.requestAccess(for: .contacts){succeeded, err in
            guard err == nil && succeeded else{
                return
            }
            self.contactList()
        }
    } else if CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts) == .authorized {
        self.contactList()
        NSLog(" move to contact list ")

    }
}

func contactList() {
    let req = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [
        CNContactFamilyNameKey as CNKeyDescriptor,
        CNContactGivenNameKey as CNKeyDescriptor,
        CNContactPhoneNumbersKey as CNKeyDescriptor
        ])

    arr_contacts.removeAllObjects()

    try! CNContactStore().enumerateContacts(with: req) {
        contact, stop in
        print("contacts \(contact)") // in real life, probably populate an array
        self.arr_contacts.add(contact)
    }

    tbl_List.reloadData()
    print("added all contacts")

}
```

Can any one suggest what am I doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `authorizationStatus`?

Comment: What is the actual authorization status?? Does `store.requestAccess` method get called?

Comment: Did you add the necessary key to the `Info.plist` file as well?

Comment: @DávidPásztor yes I have added key in my plist file Privacy - Contacts Usage Description

Comment: What is the value of `authorizationStatus`? Is the request dialog ever shown to the user? Which line throws the error, `try! CNContactStore().enumerateContacts(with: req)`?

Comment: @BadhanGanesh it print this error
Error Domain=CNErrorDomain Code=100 "Access Denied" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Access Denied, NSLocalizedFailureReason=This application has not been granted permission to access Contacts.}

Comment: Then the status might be in `.denied` state. Go to your app settings to check if the contacts permission is turned OFF.

Comment: @BadhanGanesh yes bandhan correct it's status is .denied.

Comment: Please turn it ON and it should work.

Comment: @DávidPásztor you can check it in my code I have used this too.

Comment: @ChandniSharma you didn't specify which line of code is throwing that error... However, if the status is `.denied` and you receive the error, it means that elsewhere in your code you are calling `contactList` without checking the authorization status. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code in your question, so the error most probably lies elsewhere.

Comment: @DávidPásztor: Thanks for reply but I find the solution it was due to simulator it's working fine in device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is on simulator it is working well in device and showing me access permission popup too.

Thanks guys for your great help.

Answer (score 4):

Please add this to info.plist

```
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string>App users your contacts</string>
```

Comment: I have added this key

Answer (score 2):

```
Please Add this permission in your info.plist file.

<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
 <string>App users your contacts</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody arrives here with the following error (as I did): `This application has not been granted permission to access some of the requested keys.`

This may be because you're requesting the `CNContactNoteKey` when fetching contacts. If that's the case, then you need a special permission in order to access the contact notes: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_contacts_notes?language=objc

There's currently a bug in iOS15 betas that will throw an exception unless you request `Notes` when fetching contacts, but the fetch will then fail if you do request `Notes`. So it is effectively impossible to fetch contacts in iOS15 betas unless you have the special permission. I've reported this to Apple (FB9263783).

Comment: You are a life saver! This was exactly my situation!